# Translating text to binary python

Tags: python

I need something that can turn binary into text using python.

```
new = ''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in arg)
```

I have this rn to turn text into binary, but i need a way to turn it back.

Comment: Your encoding is not injective, so in general not reversible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def binaryToText(binary):
    ''' Translating binary to text python '''

    # Split binary into an array of 8-bits
    binaryArray = [binary[i:i+8] for i in range(0, len(binary), 8)]
    return "".join(chr(int(binaryValue, 2)) for binaryValue in binaryArray)

def textToBinary(text):
    ''' Translating text to binary python '''
    # Convert text to binary
    binaryString = ""
    for character in text:
        # Get ASCII value of character
        asciiValue = ord(character)
        # Convert ASCII to binary
        binaryValue = bin(asciiValue)
        # Remove "0b" from binary
        binaryValue = binaryValue[2:]
        # Add padded zeros to make sure each binary value is 8-bits
        while len(binaryValue) < 8:
            binaryValue = f"0{binaryValue}"
        # Add this binary value to the string of binary
        binaryString += binaryValue
    return binaryString


print(binaryToText("0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000101011101101111011100100110110001100100"))
print(textToBinary("Hello World"))
```

**Output**

```
Hello World
0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000101011101101111011100100110110001100100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stream="010000010100001001000011"
"".join(chr(int(stream[i:i+8], 2)) for i in  range(0, len(stream), 8))
```